# What is a reliable approach to find anomalies in N number of images using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, anomaly-detection

I have a generated set of images, and my task is to detect which has an anomaly. The images in a generated set will always be of similar size, but the color is unknown, so I cannot filter for a specific color, etc.

My original thought was to take a standard deviation approach. I was considering collecting each color channel from each image and look for outliers.

```
def find_anomalies(data, deviation=1):
    anomalies = []
    std = np.std(data)
    median = np.median(data)
    print("std:", std)
    print("median:", median)
    anomaly_threshold = std * deviation

    lower_limit  = median - anomaly_threshold
    upper_limit = median  + anomaly_threshold
    print("upper limit:", upper_limit)
    print("lower_limit", lower_limit)
    for outlier in data:
        if outlier > upper_limit or outlier < lower_limit:
            anomalies.append(outlier)
    return anomalies
```

Unfortunately, the above approach is not reliable. To pick up the anomalies, I have to use a low deviation threshold which creates a lot of false positives.

Is there a more reliable approach here?  How do I avoid making false positives?

---

#### Dataset with an anomaly

[image]

color channel means for each image (in BGR order):

```
[array([ 57.16513605,  78.57134354, 219.78511905]),
 array([ 68.34270042,  61.33552743, 209.65704641]),
 array([ 51.3882803 , 112.60033038, 231.52756042]), # anomaly
 array([ 55.9156033 ,  89.1537716 , 221.49717332]),
 array([ 68.89410256,  60.19700855, 210.46179487])]
```

standard deviations for each image (also in BGR order):

```
[array([31.63484434, 30.85018405, 24.33004357]),
 array([35.63240512, 28.23304456, 30.03271386]),
 array([29.90787446, 38.49502507, 16.46772441]), #anomaly
 array([31.30206573, 38.42344265, 26.11348659]),
 array([35.73322784, 26.78139566, 28.99681079])]
```

---

#### Dataset with no anomalies

For completeness, here is another image set where there are no anomalies, but I get false positives.

[image]

means:

```
[array([ 49.51721236,  92.86826805, 227.2369951 ]),
 array([ 48.61022019,  76.32031575, 224.15105941]),
 array([ 51.79616963,  87.86684907, 223.92673659]),
 array([ 47.83266254, 109.75719814, 232.76904025]),
 array([ 52.66608098,  84.64163484, 222.76928953])]
```

standard deviations:

```
[array([25.93041916, 28.60078108, 18.99398738]),
 array([22.85396012, 18.91722547, 14.04923793]),
 array([27.47452402, 31.51487936, 22.9319416 ]),
 array([21.34988674, 32.60073378, 15.94599248]),
 array([29.21103562, 29.62855599, 20.87369572])]
```

---

#### My current results

Looking for outliers in just the red channel in the above two datasets

```
>>> find_anomalies(red_channels_from_dataset_with_anomaly)
[219.78511904761902, 209.6570464135021, 231.52756042427401, 221.497173316104, 210.46179487179487]
std: 8.03897659600765
median: 219.78511904761902
upper limit: 234.25527692043278
lower_limit 205.31496117480526
# => no anomalies detected (false negative)

>>> find_anomalies(red_channels_from_dataset_with_no_anomalies)
[227.23699510403915, 224.151059410054, 223.9267365861073, 232.76904024767802, 222.7692895339954]
std: 3.615494221208812
median: 224.151059410054
upper limit: 230.65894900822985
lower_limit 217.64316981187812
# => anomalies [232.76904024767802] (false positive)
```

Comment: without seeing a lot of datasets with/without anomalies it is very hard to give advice here, since domain knowledge is essential to get an idea of the variance of possible normalities/anomalies

Comment: you could have a look at a color histogram and its distribution or number of modes for example.

Comment: If you were training a fellow employee how to detect an anomaly, how, in plain English, would you describe it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would describe an anomaly as a spike of a bright color in comparison to the rest of the images.  We can expect all images to be uniform in overall color and the anomaly will be identical except they will have a spike of color in the form of a blob somewhere in the image.

Comment: Trying to be more specific, is *"spike"* the best word? The yellow in image 3 looks more like a blob than a spike to me. Is *"bright"* the correct word? Or is *"saturated"* a better word? Is it true that there are generally only 2 colours in the image but 3 or more when there is an anomaly? Is it generally true that a normal image has a uniform brightness but an area of greater brightness when there is an anomaly? I am not trying to argue, or correct you, I am trying to see if there is some feature/characteristic we can identify to find anomalies.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no worries.  When I said "spike", I'm envisioning a histogram spike.  You're right, "bright" might be a more descriptive word for what I'm trying to convey.  Counting colors may not work, because at times there is a gradient of two colors.  Regarding brightness, yes.  An anomaly will typically be a bright blob. That being said, if all of the images in the dataset were, say, orange and only one of them was green, the green image would be considered an anomaly.